# OnItemLongClickListener on Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

Hi I have Arraylist of data..I want to implement `OnItemLongClickListener` on 
each field of the arraylist. Trying to implement with `OnGestureListener` ,

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: What view do you want to assign your listener to ? Is it ListView ? You can't implement  OnItemLongClickListener to ArrayList.

Comment: You probably need to first use a ListView to display the data on your ArrayList.

Comment: @slezadav..i am getting the data from a search into the arraylist      public Adapter(Activity activity, int viewResourceId,
   ArrayList<Data> items, int renderer,
   ArrayList<Data> mydata, double latitute,
   double longitute,String menuId) { ......}

Comment: @slezadav..here is the code for arraylist..http://pastebin.com/zvjt98ft    is there anyother listener to implement on Arraylist like onlongclick?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using List view..
Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do your stuff here
   }
});
```